# How to build layout with automatic width in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to figure out how to make [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG9Yj.png) layout in flutter. I want it to have to columns and as indefinite rows, is there a way in which the column would change it's width depending on the child with the largest width?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lbE0wsVZSw

Comment: Thanks man! Only knew the material DataTable, which didn't fit my needs. This is perfect